# How to get multiple values by executing the shell script and use the same in the program?

Tags: c, bash, shell

I want to obtain available space and total space of the system(take any one partition for example) by excuting shell script. store them into variable and use them in my current c program .
my c code is

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        char uSpace[10],aSpace[10];
            system("/home/amitk/projects/amit_bk/practice/space.sh");

        //to do: store the used space and available space into uSpace , aSpace and print them. 
    return 0;
}
```

and my script **space.sh** is

```
x=`df -h /dev/sr0| awk '{print $3}'`
sleep 1
echo $x
y=`df -h /dev/sr0| awk '{print $4}'`
sleep 1
echo $y
```

Say I get result as x=82 Mb and y=10Mb. So these values I want to store into uSpace and aSpace. How do I do it?

Comment: What's wrong with calling stat() on /dev/sr0 within the c code?

Comment: @oguzismail bt how to use it and obtain these 2 values

Comment: is it possible to pass address of the uSpace and aSpace varible into the shell .so that values will get updated there

Comment: As you can see from the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl), `execl` **replaces** the current process by _bash_ or _sh_ (depending on the #! line of your script), so your C-program would not exist anymore for evaluating anything, once the script started to run. You could either manually implement a solution involving `fork` and `wait`, or - simpler - use `system` instead of `execl`. Then have your script write the required values to a file, and from within your C program, read this file.

Comment: @user1934428 ok i done related code changes now is it possible to pass address of the uSpace and aSpace varible into the shell .so that values will get updated there??

Comment: I don't see that you write the data to a file, as I suggested. If you want to proceed with your current shell script, you need to read the stdout from your script. If you want to do it, you have to go with `fork` and `wait`, as I told you. You find a recipe how to do this [here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html). If you communicate the data over a file, it is probably less work and easier to debug.

Comment: And your wrote "now is it possible to pass address of the uSpace and aSpace varible into the shell". No, that will never be possible. Recall the basic *nix process model is `parent->child` where a child can only return data via std-out (or write files) that the parent can read. The child can make not direct modification to the running parent process. (at least that is how I interpret your Q).  The link provideed aby @user1934428 is the way to go. Good luck!

Comment: And of course, that begs the question of writting a low level program that only calls a high level program (chain) to achieve what can be done natively with the low-level programming language. Again .... good luck! ;-)

Comment: @user3559780: Of course, as shelllter commented, we can not pass addresses around, but of course if the child process write the data to a file, the parent process can read the relevant part of theís file  into the arrays `uSpace` and `aSpace`. I think this is what want to achieve in the end.